# Delphi TGridLayout layout and padding between items

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I have gotten some results trying to use TGridLayout to hold series of TImage object each with a  bitmap loaded. However, there is no margin between the cotrols. I have already tried to make the TImage width/height smaller than TGridLayout itemheight/itemwidth, but no luck.

Example code:

```
ImageRef := TImage.Create(GridLayoutGallery);
ImageRef.Visible := False; // se true later
ImageRef.Width := GridLayoutGallery.ItemWidth - 10;
ImageRef.Height := GridLayoutGallery.ItemHeight - 10;
GridLayoutGallery.AddObject(ImageRef);
```

Comment: Did you try setting `YourImage.AlignWithMargins` to `True` and then adjusting the `YourImage.Margins` property?

Comment: @LightBulb, by setting the margins to each individual image will cause the image to shrink and the quality will suffer. Ultimately the size of each object in the layout is decided by the GridLayout component itself.

Comment: @LightBulb Thanks. This suggestion actually works, and I will use for now until I get more time to experiment with the other solutions suggested. (I am on a pretty tight schedule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close to an answer yourself, here is how I would achieve this:

Lets say your Grid holds a series of Images with a size of 40 x 40 px

[image]

To apply the margin between the images simply set the [ItemWidth](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Layouts.TGridLayout.ItemWidth) and [ItemHeight](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Layouts.TGridLayout.ItemHeight) properties of the [TGridLayout](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Layouts.TGridLayout) component to a value larger then the size of the actual image, for example 42 x 42 px.

[image]

This should create a margin around every Image placed in the TGridLayout.

Comment: @Tom, your solution did not work because you tried to change the actual width and height of the Timage control, it does not work like that. as I have said, TGridLayout controls the size of the control. Any size that your TImage was before you inserted it into the layout is reset to the values set by TGridLayout.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. It will be a little messy though since I have a routine that size Bitmaps optimally to fit inside my TImage, but I guess I will rewrite that unless I find another solution! :)

Comment: @Tom, it shouldn't be messy at all, all you have to make sure is that the Width and the Height of the TImage is smaller then the values used in the TGridLayour Height and WIdth properties.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the description of the TGridLayout:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Layouts.TGridLayout

> The children of a **TGridLayout** are resized to fit the sizes specified through the ItemHeight and ItemWidth properties. [...] However, you can customize sizes of child controls using the Margins properties of child controls.
>   [image: Image taken from Embarcadero]

-> Set ItemHeight and ItemWidth to (ImageSize + MarginSize)
-> Set Margins of the images to (MarginSize)